# Correct breakdown of the name of secp256k1?

Tags: cryptography

```
sec Standards for Efficient Cryptography
256 256bit prime
k1 Koblitz curve no. 1
?
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Should be `p256` for curve over a prime finite field (which mathematicians abbreviate Fp) with a 256-bit (prime) modulus. The much-less-used `sec t <n> {k,r}<i>` curves are over F2^n fields, finite extension fields with characteristic two, where the t abbreviates two.